# Некорректный вывод массива

Tags: java, массивы, наследование, arraylist, интерфейс

имеется следующее задание:

Организовать базу (массив) объектов типа интерфейс, которую заполнить объектами описанных типов вперемежку (по желанию пользователя). Выполнить следующие действия:

- вывести полную информацию обо всех объектах массива;
- найти в массиве объекты, функциональный метод которых возвращают одинаковый результат, поместить такие объекты в другой массив;
- разбить исходный массив на два массива, в которых будут храниться однотипные элементы;

Моя проблема заключается в том, что я прописал заполнение массива случайными объектами, однако, когда я хочу вывести этот массив на экран, мне всё время выдают разные результаты. Мой код:

Сам интерфейс:

```
interface VehicleAndWorkers
{
    String cars();
}
```

Первый класс, реализующий интерфейс:

```
public class TaxiStation implements VehicleAndWorkers{
TrucksLogistic trucks = new TrucksLogistic();

public String[] cars = {"KIA", "Hyundai", "Volkswagen", "Lada", "Datsun", "Skoda"};
int quantCars = 150;
int workers = 300;

public String cars() {
    System.out.println("Список моделей нашего таксопарка: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(cars[i]);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    return trucks.quantTrucks == this.quantCars;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(trucks, quantCars);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return cars();
 }
}
```

Второй класс, реализующий интерфейс:

```
public class TrucksLogistic implements VehicleAndWorkers {

    String[] trucks = {"Kenworth W900", "Volvo FH16", "Scania R730", "MAN TGS 18.400", "МАЗ 6430", 
    "КАМАЗ-5490 НЕО 2"};

    int quantTrucks = 40;
    int workers = 100;

    public String cars()
    {
        System.out.println("Список моделей нашей компании: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < trucks.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(trucks[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Количество работников: " + workers);
        System.out.println("Количество грузовиков:" + quantTrucks);
        System.out.println("Отношение количества моделей грузовиков к количеству грузовиков: " + Math.round(trucks.length / quantTrucks));

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return cars();
    }

}
```

Класс, в котором я пытался реализовать работу с ArrayList (заполнение, отображение и т.д.):

```
public class InterfaceArray {
ArrayList<VehicleAndWorkers> array = new ArrayList<>();

public void setArray() {
    int randomLength = (int) Math.floor(random() * 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < randomLength; i++) {
        Random random = new Random();

        int minRandomNum = 1;
        int maxRandomNum = 2;
        int diffRandomNum = maxRandomNum - minRandomNum;
        int randomNum = random.nextInt(diffRandomNum + 1) + minRandomNum;

        if (randomNum == 1) {
            array.add(new TrucksLogistic() {
                @Override
                public String cars() {
                    int num = (int) Math.floor(random() * trucks.length);
                    quantTrucks = (int) Math.floor(random() * 100);

                    Random random = new Random();

                    int minWorkers = quantTrucks;
                    int maxWorkers = 200;
                    int diffWorkers = maxWorkers - minWorkers;

                    workers = random.nextInt(diffWorkers + 1);
                    workers += minWorkers;

                    System.out.println("Количество грузовиков: " + quantTrucks);
                    System.out.println("Количество работников: " + workers);
                    System.out.println("Среднее количество работников на 1 грузовик: " + Math.round(workers / quantTrucks));

                    return "Приоритетная марка/модель грузовика: " + trucks[num];
                }
            });
        } else {

            array.add(new TaxiStation() {
                @Override
                public String cars() {
                    int num = (int) Math.floor(random() * cars.length);
                    quantCars = (int) Math.floor(random() * 100);

                    Random random = new Random();

                    int minWorkers = quantCars;
                    int maxWorkers = 200;
                    int diffWorkers = maxWorkers - minWorkers;

                    workers = random.nextInt(diffWorkers + 1);
                    workers += minWorkers;

                    System.out.println("Количество легковых автомобилей: " + quantCars);
                    System.out.println("Количество работников: " + workers);
                    System.out.println("Среднее количество работников на 1 автомобиль: " + Math.round(workers / quantCars));

                    return "Приоритетная марка/модель легкового автомобиля: " + cars[num];
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

public void getArray() {
    for (VehicleAndWorkers element : array) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(element);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public void sameElements() {
 ////          Set<VehicleAndWorkers> arrayTwo = new LinkedHashSet<>(array);
 ////         for (VehicleAndWorkers element : arrayTwo)
 ////            System.out.println(element + "\n");
 //
 //        for (int element = 0; element < array.size() - 1; element++)
 //        {
 //            for (int i = element + 1; i < array.size(); element++)
 //            {
 //                if (array.get(element).equals(element + 1))
 //                {
 //                    arrayTwo.add(array.get(element + 1));
 //                }
 //            }
 //            array.remove(array.get(element));
 //        }
 //        for (VehicleAndWorkers element : arrayTwo)
 //            System.out.println(element.toString());

}

public void sameTypeElements() {
    ArrayList<VehicleAndWorkers> arrayTwo = new ArrayList<>();
  //                for (VehicleAndWorkers element : array)
  //                {
  //                    if (element)
  //                }
        }
    }
```

Ну и класс, в котором применяются методы из предыдущего класса

```
public class ConsoleInterface {
void doChoice()
{
    InterfaceArray interfaceArray = new InterfaceArray();

    printOptions();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = scan.nextInt();

    while (choice >= 0 && choice < 5) {
        if (choice == 0) {
            interfaceArray.setArray();
            interfaceArray.getArray();
            printOptions();
            choice = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else if (choice == 1) {
            interfaceArray.setArray();
            printOptions();
            choice = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            interfaceArray.sameElements();
            printOptions();
            choice = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else if (choice == 3) {
            interfaceArray.sameTypeElements();
            printOptions();
            choice = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else if (choice == 4) {
            interfaceArray.getArray();
            printOptions();
            choice = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
}

void printOptions()
{
    System.out.println("Выберите действие: \n");
    System.out.println("0 - Заполнить массив случайными элементами и вывести его на экран. \n");
    System.out.println("1 - Заполнить массив случайными элементами. \n");
    System.out.println("2 - Найти в массиве объекты,\n" +
            "      функциональный метод которых возвращает одинаковый результат. \n");
    System.out.println("3 - Разбить исходный массив на два массива,\n" +
                    "      в которых будут храниться однотипные элементы. \n");
    System.out.println("4 - Вывести массив(-ы) на экран. \n");
    System.out.println("Любая клавиша - Выйти из приложения. \n");
 }
}
```

Пример работы программы:

1. Заполняю массив и сразу вывожу его в консоль: https://prnt.sc/113e6n6
2. Получаю результат: https://prnt.sc/113e7qn
3. Пытаюсь опять вывести все объекты массива: https://prnt.sc/113e8zj
4. Иии... Получаю совершенно другие результаты: https://prnt.sc/113e9cx

Честно, не знаю, в чём может быть проблема, преподаватель в университете тоже развёл руками, поэтому буду рад любой критике, замечаниям и предложениям. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Я тоже развожу руками. Задание и решение представляют собой полную белиберду.

Comment: "найти в массиве объекты, функциональный метод которых возвращают одинаковый результат" - я знаю все слова в этом предложении, но что хотел сказать автор - могу только догадываться.

Comment: абсолютно согласен с предыдущим комментарием. я такого , пожалуй, еще не видел. вы нарушили вообще все, что только можно нарушить, начиная с самых базовых принципов таких, как инкапсуляция. это равносильно тому, что взять словарь, перемешать все слова в нем, а потом опубликовать как собрание сочинений. единственный совет - удалите этот код и напишите новую реализацию с ноля. здесь исправлять нечего

Comment: если вы хотите знать, почему на экране другие данные, то это не сложно: вы переопределяете метод public String cars() в классе InterfaceArray при вызове setArray() таким образом, что при каждом вызове этого метода его полям присваиваются рандомные значения. дальше , сколько бы вы не вызывали метод getArray() переопределенный метод public String cars()  будет отдавать рандом, выводя на экран при каждом вызове новые данные. отсюда новые данные на экране, но это никак не отменяет предыдущего комментария

Comment: Это только один из пунктов задания, вот полное: https://prnt.sc/113oz4y . Может быть поэтому задание кажется бредом.

Comment: И как мне объяснили в университете, "найти в массиве объекты, функциональный метод которых возвращают одинаковый результат, поместить такие объекты в другой массив" - это когда 2 (или более) объектов возвращают одинаковый результат, у меня это, например, может быть "Lada" и "Lada" или "Volvo FH16" и "Volvo FH16".  "Разбить исходный массив на два массива, в которых будут храниться однотипные элементы" - это объекты, переопределяющие метод одного и того же класса. Если 1 и 2 объект переопределяет метод от TaxiStation - они однотипные (конкретно в моём случае).

Comment: решение кажется бредом. а задание в исходном виде дает достаточно свободы действий для решения задачи.

Comment: @Дмитрий, Можете подсказать, как наилучшим образом стоит переделать код?

Comment: на все вопросы я уже ответил. вы не понимали, почему вы получаете разные результат - я вам это объяснил. переделать код  - оно того не стоит, проще написать с ноля. я это тоже уже написал. все что вам нужно - простейшая реализация полиморфизма. условия задания позволяет взять любой пример. не можете придумать хороший пример с полиморфизмом - найдите в инете. если возникнут вопросы в процессе реализации - задавайте вопросы. когда пишите код , придерживайтесь GARSP, SOLID , не забывайте про принципы ООП. если не знаете что это - почитайте. я не знаю, чем еще могу вам помочь